# How to access element of Tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am new to Python and doing some hands on.

I have a list of tuples of tuples (each tuple is having 3 sub-tuples) as below:

```
ABC = [   (('The', 'AT'), ('Fulton', 'NP-TL'), ('County', 'NN-TL')),   

(('Fulton', 'NP-TL'), ('County', 'NN-TL'), ('Grand', 'JJ-TL')), 

(('County', 'NN-TL'), ('Grand', 'JJ-TL'), ('Jury', 'NN-TL')), 

(('Grand', 'JJ-TL'), ('Jury', 'NN-TL'), ('said', 'VBD')), 

(('Jury', 'NN-TL'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('Friday', 'NR'))   ]
```

I need to extract the second value of sub-tuple in each tuple i.e. 3 values and get them in a Tuple , which will be added in list.

Please assist how to get this.

Expected result:

I need a new list derived from it as:

```
 ABC_subset = [('AT','NP-TL', 'NN-TL'),

('NP-TL','NN-TL', 'JJ-TL'),

('NN-TL','JJ-TL', 'NN-TL'),

('JJ-TL','NN-TL', 'VBD'),

('NN-TL','VBD', 'NR')]
```

I am trying something like this:

```
 ABC_subset = [(t[1],u[1],v[1]) for tup in ABC for t,u,v in tup]
```

But it is not giving the expected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a List Comprehension like:

```
output = [tuple(j[1] for j in i) for i in inputlist]
```

You will need to convert the second expression to a tuple as else it would output a generator object

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your first list is `orig` and the second list that you want is `newlist`. It can be done very simply with list comprehensions:

```
newlist = [tuple(j[1] for j in i) for i in orig]
```

Essentially, iterate through each row `i` of `orig`, and extract the second element from each tuple `j` in that row.

Comment: This will return a list of generators.

Comment: That's fair. I added a cast to `tuple` which should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
[(x[1] for x in y) for y in your_list]
```

Comment: This will return a list of generators. Also, it would be nice to add some explanation to the code.